# SyntaxError: Unexpected token export when unit trying to unit test Microsoft API library function calls in SPFx

Tags: spfx

I have these tests, the first one passes, but I can't get my mounting to work properly:

```
import 'jest';
import * as React from 'react';
import { configure, mount, ReactWrapper } from 'enzyme';
import * as Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import Todolist from '../Todolist';
import MockHttpClient from './mock/SPHttpClient'


test('1+1 should equal 2', () => {
  const result = 1+1;
  expect(result).toBe(2);
});

describe('Enzyme basics', () => {

    let reactComponent: ReactWrapper<any, any>;

    beforeEach(() => {

      reactComponent = mount(React.createElement(
        Todolist,
        {
          spHttpClient: MockHttpClient, //provider
          siteUrl: '',
          description: '',
        }
      ));
    });

    afterEach(() => {
      reactComponent.unmount();
    });

    it('should root web part element exists', () => {

      // define the css selector
      let cssSelector: string = '';

      // find the element using css selector
      const element = reactComponent.find(cssSelector);
      expect(element.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    });

    it('should has the correct title', () => {

      // Arrange
      // define contains/like css selector
      let cssSelector: string = 'h1';

      // Act
      // find the elemet using css selector
      const text = reactComponent.find(cssSelector).text();

      // Assert
      expect(text).toBe("");  
    });
  });
```

This is my mock:

```
export default class MockHttpClient  {

    private static _items: any[] = [{ Title: 'Mock List', Id: '1' },
                                        { Title: 'Mock List 2', Id: '2' },
                                        { Title: 'Mock List 3', Id: '3' }];

    public static get(): Promise<any[]> {
    return new Promise<any[]>((resolve) => {
            resolve(MockHttpClient._items);
        });
    }
}
```

This is one of the function inside the component I am trying to test:

```
getListItemEntityTypeName = async (): Promise<string> => {
    return new Promise<string>((resolve: (listItemEntityTypeName: string) => void, reject: (error: any) => void): void => {
      if (this.listItemEntityTypeName) {
        resolve(this.listItemEntityTypeName);
        return;
      }
      this.props.spHttpClient.get(`${this.props.siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ToDo')?$select=ListItemEntityTypeFullName`,
        SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
        {
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata',
            'odata-version': ''
          }
        })
        .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<{ ListItemEntityTypeFullName: string }> => {
          return response.json();
        }, (error: any): void => {
          reject(error);
        })
        .then((response: { ListItemEntityTypeFullName: string }): void => {
          this.listItemEntityTypeName = response.ListItemEntityTypeFullName;
          resolve(this.listItemEntityTypeName);
        });
    });

  }
```

I need to mock this.props.spHttpClient to make my tests successful, but I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\github\crud-simple\node_modules\@microsoft\sp-http\lib\index.js:12
export { default as HttpClient } from './httpClient/HttpClient';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

It's like it's trying to read spHttpClient from Microsoft's internal library when I specify the this.props.spHttpClient is of type spHttpClient. Is there a way to avoid this issue? Is it even feasible to unit test Microsoft's API library?